# What's the most efficient way of using structs?

Tags: c

I have the following struct and an array of structs as shown below.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t configuration,
    uint8_t count_1, count_2, count_3, count_4;
} *zonePtr, zoneT;

typedef enum {
    CONFIG_1,
    CONFIG_2,
    CONFIG_3,
    CONFIG_4
} config_t;

const zoneT zones[5] = {
    { CONFIG_1, 1, 2, 0, 0 },
    { CONFIG_1, 3, 5, 0, 0 },
    { CONFIG_2, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
    { CONFIG_4, 2, 6, 7, 3 },
    { CONFIG_3, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
};
```

In the zones array, we can see some `count_x` members have been initialized to 0, this means they aren't being used and it's just a waste of those extra bytes. Only those `count_x` members that have been initialized to anything other than 0 are being used. In case if we have a large array of size 100, then this way of holding the configuration data will lead to a lot of memory being wasted.

My question is, in this scenario, what's the most efficient but yet flexible way of doing the above and prevent waste of space?

Comment: What's the maximum value of such members?

Comment: As it’s generally acknowledged that effort spent on premature optimisation is often much better spent working on correct design and function, do you actually need to worry about this wasted space - is a few hundred bytes going to make much difference to your project?

Comment: @DavidRanieri, the maximum value is always less than 255.

Comment: Seems like the total array size will be somewhere between 500 and 1000 bytes. Is that really a problem?

Comment: @barny, not really, but the question is just out of interest to know if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: @VinayDivakar in such case you can not compress them, for shorter values (i.e 0 ...7) you can use bit shifts `{CONFIG_1, (1 << 1) | (1 << 2)},` and avoid using `count_2, count_3, count_4`

Comment: @DavidRanieri, for values between 0 to 7, I am aware of that method.

Comment: OK looks like it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Trying to save memory for something like this is something you should avoid until absolutely necessary. And if you really need it, you would likely need to study your particular problem in extreme detail.

Comment: You could make `configuration` a bit field with only 2 bits, but unless you can save space somewhere else, the padding will eat it up.

Comment: Your example gives the impression that if count_x is zero, then count_x+1 is also zero. Could that be the case?

Comment: @klutt, yes that's correct.

Comment: That's possible to exploit. Will the values change during the execution? Or more to the point, will they change between zero and non-zero?

Comment: No, they don't change during execution. Initialized just once at the beginning.

Comment: Specifically, what're the limits on the data, what are the additional constraints on the data (eg: if one length is zero, then so is the next), and how will it be used? Without this, optimizing is just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, optimizations aim for faster code is the primary concern, not so much  shaving a few bytes of RAM use here and there. Your concern for wasting some 100 bytes doesn't make sense at all on mid- to high-end computers like PC. It's mainly very low end microcontroller applications that need to chase stray RAM bytes here and there.

Then taking a closer look, `const zoneT zones[5] = ...` actually looks like a read-only constant. So this doesn't even go on the moderately resource-constrained stack, but in some read-only linker section `.rodata`. Now even the crappiest 8 bit MCU is no longer concerned, because this would end up in flash, not RAM.

So no matter how you put this, this smells like big time "pre-mature optimization". But lets ignore that and see how we could actually improve the code if we were to optimize it...:

---

Ok so lets assume we have for some reason decided that this code is a bottleneck for memory and/or speed. We don't care about readability or maintainability, we just want raw program efficiency.

The main concern here is that you've made a struct with 5 bytes. That's bad, computers hate everything which isn't a multiple of 2. They particularly tend to adore chunks of 4 bytes, especially them 32 bit CPUs. For this reason, some compilers may decide to toss in padding bytes in the struct, making it 8 bytes large. Not so likely when all members are `char` but extremely likely in case of `typedef struct { uint8_t configuration; int foo; }`

This means that any sound optimization should focus on reducing the size of the struct to 4 bytes. You may for example ask yourself if you really need each "count" to cover values 0-255. Or could we for example do with 0-127?

We could then create a fairly icky but very fast bit-field, by letting each 7 bit count value sit where it currently sits, but abuse the MSB of each byte for storing the config.

Start by coming up with some bit masks:

```
#define CONFIG_1 0x80000000u
#define CONFIG_2 0x00800000u
#define CONFIG_3 0x00008000u
#define CONFIG_4 0x00000080u
#define CONFIG_MASK (CONFIG_1 | CONFIG_2 | CONFIG_3 | CONFIG_4)
```

Now, assuming little endian, we can initialize the whole thing like this instead:

```
const uint32_t zone [5] = 
{ 
  CONFIG_1 | (1u << 0 | 2u << 8 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 24),
  CONFIG_1 | (3u << 0 | 5u << 8 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 24),
  CONFIG_2 | (2u << 0 | 0u << 8 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 24),
  CONFIG_4 | (2u << 0 | 6u << 8 | 7 << 16 | 3 << 24),
  CONFIG_3 | (1u << 0 | 2u << 8 | 3 << 16 | 4 << 24)
};
```

This is optimized for speed and memory both, pretty much on any generic computer. Is it pretty? No, it's pretty awful. But efficient. Full code example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONFIG_1 0x80000000u
#define CONFIG_2 0x00800000u
#define CONFIG_3 0x00008000u
#define CONFIG_4 0x00000080u
#define CONFIG_MASK (CONFIG_1 | CONFIG_2 | CONFIG_3 | CONFIG_4)

#define ZONE_VALUE_MASK 0x7Fu

const uint32_t zone [5] = 
{ 
  CONFIG_1 | (1u << 0 | 2u << 8 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 24),
  CONFIG_1 | (3u << 0 | 5u << 8 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 24),
  CONFIG_2 | (2u << 0 | 0u << 8 | 0 << 16 | 0 << 24),
  CONFIG_4 | (2u << 0 | 6u << 8 | 7 << 16 | 3 << 24),
  CONFIG_3 | (1u << 0 | 2u << 8 | 3 << 16 | 4 << 24)
};

const char* get_config (uint32_t u32)
{
  switch(u32 & CONFIG_MASK)
  {
    case CONFIG_1: return "CONFIG_1"; 
    case CONFIG_2: return "CONFIG_2"; 
    case CONFIG_3: return "CONFIG_3"; 
    case CONFIG_4: return "CONFIG_4"; 
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    printf("%s ", get_config(zone[i]));
    
    const uint8_t* byte = (uint8_t*)&zone[i];
    for(size_t j=0; j<sizeof(zone[i]); j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", byte[j] & ZONE_VALUE_MASK);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Output

```
CONFIG_1 1 2 0 0 
CONFIG_1 3 5 0 0 
CONFIG_2 2 0 0 0 
CONFIG_4 2 6 7 3 
CONFIG_3 1 2 3 4
```

Now the string handling function in this example is just some "quick & dirty" one and the `printf` are obviously painfully slow. But the actual data iteration is very fast, memory-efficient and cache-friendly.

(And as it happens much more portable than a struct, save for the mentioned endianess issue during initialization. We could fix that up too by swapping the `uint32_t` for a union, but that's another story and not related to performance.)

Comment: And to treat this as a plain 4 byte value array, just `zone[i] & ~CONFIG_MASK`.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do stuff like this unless ABSOLUTELY necessary.**

From comments:

If count_x is zero, then count_x+1 is also zero. So instead of storing them individually, keep them in a long array and store the offset in the struct. Also, you can use bit fields. `configuration` has four possible values, and the number of `count_x` is also maximum four.

```
struct {
  uint8_t configuration : 2;
  uint8_t no_count      : 2;
  uint8_t offset        : 12;
} zoneT[size];

uint8_t count[size];
```

And then get `count_x` with

```
c = count[zoneT[index]->offset + x]
```

Make sure that `x<no_count`

The size of the offset field could possibly be lower, but padding will set the limit here and a size of 4 is likely to little. You could skip the offset field completely at the cost of cpu time, because it's possible to calculate it by adding all `no_count` up to the element in `zoneT` that you want. Something like this:

```
struct {
  uint8_t configuration : 2;
  uint8_t no_count      : 2;
} zoneT[size];

uint8_t count[size];

uint8_t offset = 0;
for(int i=0; i<index; i++) 
    offset += zoneT[i]->no_count;
c = count[offset];
```

Note here that this only uses 4 bits in the struct. You could save some padding waste by having two in each:

```
struct {
  uint8_t configuration1 : 2;
  uint8_t no_count1      : 2;
  uint8_t configuration2 : 2;
  uint8_t no_count2      : 2;
} zoneT[size/2];

uint8_t count[size];
```

Most likely, this will only lead to slow and unmaintainable code.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this and have absolutely no 'wasted' variables:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t configuration,
  uint32_t length;
  uint8_t *counts;
} *zonePtr, zoneT;

typedef enum{
 CONFIG_1,
 CONFIG_2,
 CONFIG_3,
 CONFIG_4
} config_t;

uint8_t count1[] = { 1, 2 };
uint8_t count2[] = { 3, 5 };
uint8_t count3[] = { 2 };
uint8_t count4[] = { 2, 6, 7, 3 };
uint8_t count5[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

zoneT zones[5] = {
 {CONFIG_1, sizeof(count1) / sizeof(uint8_t), &count1 },
 {CONFIG_1, sizeof(count2) / sizeof(uint8_t), &count2 },
 {CONFIG_2, sizeof(count3) / sizeof(uint8_t), &count3 },
 {CONFIG_4, sizeof(count4) / sizeof(uint8_t), &count4 },
 {CONFIG_3, sizeof(count5) / sizeof(uint8_t), &count5 },
};
```

My solution is great if you can have much more than just 4 values for 'count'.
Because just storing the length and the pointer to the counts is 8 bytes, plus another byte for each value of 'count'. While the original solution used an array of 4 bytes.

I guess the lesson is sometimes it's more efficient to have 'wasted' space, and sometimes you can use a more complex solution to avoid it, but it depends on the program.

Comment: does `uint8_t *count1 = { 1, 2 };` really work?

Comment: Storing a uint32 and a pointer is less memory-efficient than storing 4 uint8. The struct described here will be 12 or 16 bytes rather than the original's 8 bytes, and it's more complicated to manage the memory because it's not all inline.

Comment: @PaulHankin That is exactly what i said

Comment: @mch It does, because an array is just a pointer. it is the same as ```uint8_t count1[] = { 1, 2 };```

Comment: OK, so it seems like you're not answering the question as written. You're making a correct point that if there's many counts rather than 4 (and assuming there's significantly many shorter arrays of counts) this solution will eventually use less memory, but there's no indication in the question that the number of counts will be above 4.